# get html value on checkbox click from a table using jquery 

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

I am creating a dynamic table like below on page load after fetching data from database

```
<table border="1" id="tableView">
        <thead>
            <th></th><th>ID</th><th>Name</th><th>Description</th><th>Active</th><th>Release Date</th>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
        <%
        for(int i=0;i<result.size();i++)
        {
            %><tr><td><input class="tablechkbox" type="checkbox"/></td><%
            String[] row=pi.getResults(result,i,params);
            for(int j=0;j<row.length;j++)
            {
                %><td class="viewa"><%out.print(row[j]);%></td><%
            }
            %></tr><%
        } %>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

This is what I am doing to fetch `ID` column. Please help me fetch any specific column

```
$('#tableView tbody tr').live('click', function (event) {
        if ($('input.tablechkbox', this).is(':checked'))
        {
            alert(this.innerHTMl());
            /*$('.viewa', this).each(function() {
                alert(this.innerHTMl());
            });*/
        }
    });
```

Below is my jsp page screenshot

[image]

Comment: you'd better post the `HTML` code instead of the `JSP`. Could you explain your question `Please help me fetch any specific column`?

Comment: @JMax: any specific column means any one of "ID,Name,Description,Active,Release Date"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

alert($(this).find("td:eq(1)").html()); should work

Answer (score 0):

Consider storing the row Id in your row using an HTML5 data- attribute (the prefix allows you to define arbitrary attributes that are "legal"):

```
String[] row = pi.getResults(result, i, params);
%>
<tr data-id="<%=row[0]%>">
    <td><input class="tablechkbox" type="checkbox" /></td>
```

That way, you can grab the Id directly from the clicked row:

```
$('#tableView tbody tr').live('click', function (event) {
    if ($('input.tablechkbox', this).is(':checked')) {
        var id = $(this).data("id")
```

You can use `$(this).attr("data-id")` in older versions of jQuery.